# Android Studio auto detect and suggest new libraries version

Tags: android, dependencies, version

I have this case, I created "denpendencies.grandle" file and add some libraries version and add it to build.gradle.

here is dependencies in build.gradle ( Module )

```
apply from: 'dependencies.gradle'


dependencies {

    //Fragment
    implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:${fragment_version}"

    //Room
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:${room_version}"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:${room_version}"
    ksp "androidx.room:room-compiler:${room_version}"

    //Gson
    implementation "com.google.code.gson:gson:${gson_version}" 
}
```

and denpendencies.gradle

```
ext{
    room_version = "2.6.1"
    lifecycle_version = "2.6.2"
    nav_version = "2.7.6"
    coroutines_version = "1.7.3"
    retrofit_version = "2.9.0"
    fragment_version = "1.6.2"
}
```

such is the example. If i code like this then the IDE wont suggest new libraries version.
I want to ask you guys how to make IDE ( Android Studio ) detect and suggest for us new libraries version if make the define version like above.

Answer (score 0):

1. If your ide not showing the latest version , then you can search for the library in [mavenCentral](https://mvnrepository.com/) , the latest version will be displayed there(if available)
2. replace ${room_version},${gson_version}, etc with numeric version string.
3. Press CONTROL + SHIFT + ALT +S ,  an window will be pop up , click on suggestion you will see your dependencies all version , rollback to previous or update.

Comment: thank you but it's not the answer i expected.